# For loop doesn't work but while loop does

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

I've created a function that create borders around a special area (those information are stocked in the following table of struct):

```
typedef struct s_letter_stock
{
    int element_nb;
    int width;
    int height;
    t_pos square_p1;
    t_pos square_p2;
} g_letter_stock;
//those values are for the example
g_letter_stock letter_infos[] = {{ 0, 0, 0, {0, 0}, {0, 0} },
                                 { 0, 0, 0, {0, 0}, {0, 0} }};
```

I found a crazy bug: the for `loop` in the function below works great the first time but then it stops like if there was a break at the end of the loop (and when I print `nb_elem` its having the right value). So basically I've no clue why `for` is stopping while the `while` (in comments) works. Do you have any idea about this weird behavior? I'm out of ideas.

```
void create_borders(char **map, int nb_elem)
{
    printf("nb_elem : %d\n", nb_elem);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nb_elem ; i++) //THIS dosnt work and stop once i = 1
        // int i = 0;                    //ALL the commentes are part of the other
        // int j = 0;                    //solution that i found which is working
        // while (j < nb_elem)
    {
        int newx = -1;
        int newy = -1;
        while (newx <= letter_infos[i].width + 1 ||
               newy <= letter_infos[i].height + 1)
        {
            if (letter_infos[i].square_p1.y - 1 >= 0 &&
                newx <= letter_infos[i].width + 1)
                map[letter_infos[i].square_p1.y - 1][letter_infos[i].square_p1.x + newx] = '@';
            if (letter_infos[i].square_p1.x - 1 >= 0 &&
                newy <= letter_infos[i].height + 1)
                    map[letter_infos[i].square_p1.y +
                        newy][letter_infos[i].square_p1.x - 1] = '@';
            if (letter_infos[i].square_p2.y + 1 < strlen (map[0]) &&
                newx <= letter_infos[i].width + 1)
                map[letter_infos[i].square_p2.y + 1][letter_infos[i].square_p2.x - newx] = '@';
            if (letter_infos[i].square_p2.x + 1 < my_tablen (map) &&
                newy <= letter_infos[i].height + 1)
                map[letter_infos[i].square_p2.y - newy][letter_infos[i].square_p2.x + 1] = '@';
            newx++;
            newy++;
        }
        printf ("i = %d\n", i);
        i++;
        //j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: does the `i++` at the very end also belong to the `while`-variant, and you just forgot to comment it out?

Comment: Just try to delete `i++` in the bottom near `j++`

Comment: Damn man.... that's the reason why it doesn't work.... I don't know why i put it there in the first place. Well, I feel stupid but at least I've my answer thanks.

Comment: If you have another question, please don't edit it into your question but rather ask it in a separate question post, but you should be able to figure out the answers to both questions by making a [mcve] and/or [debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Dukeling ok thank's I was wondering how to edit a question since for now I haven't seen anyone do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that each loop has 2 execution times `i++` (at `for (int i = 0 ; i < nb_elem ; i++)` and at the end of loop)

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the statement :

```
i++;
```

at the bottom of your `for` loop, as you already increment `i` in the third part of your `for` condition.